# Number of photons through glass

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, reflection

I am getting mixed information on the total photon count involved with light transmission through glass. I'm not looking for percentages and I don't have equipment to count photons.

For simplicity say you shine laser that produces 1000 photons per second through glass. I know that depending on the glass thickness the reflection from the front surface can range between 0 and 16% but that doesn't tell me the number of photons.

A side from photons absorbed in the glass (hopefully minimally) are there charts that show the actual photon counts:
(1) After going through the glass.
(2) Reflected back.

Are there charts for different thicknesses of glass?
For example could a light source of 1000 photons per second transmits 656 photons, reflect 125 and refract or absorb the other 219? In short are all the photons accounted for? Thanks

Comment: That's fairly trivial... 90% transmitted power means that 90% of the photons will go trough the glass... if you are a religious believer in photons being small balls of fire, which they are not, of course, but at the level of your question it doesn't matter. The photon count before and after the glass will be given by the transmitted power and it's really as simple as that. If you also have the absorption and reflection numbers, then all the photons should be "accounted for".

Comment: What ever they look like they make individual impacts and can be detected. So my question is if 1000 photons are emitted, are they all accounted for between those transmitted, reflected and other?

Comment: In other words as the glass thickness changes and reflection goes from 0% to 16% does that mean 16% of the original light source or is it a 16/84 relation between those transmitted through the glass  with the total number not equaling 1000?

Comment: Photons account for energy, momentum and angular momentum of the light and these quantities are conserved. Sometimes, as in your trivial scenario, one can account for that with a fixed, additive number of photons and at other times one can not. When one can and when one can not requires an intimate understanding of what a photon really is.

Comment: So that's what I am looking for. Those times where "one can account for that with a fixed, additive number of photons"

Comment: I don't know if there is a trivial criterion for that. For instance, in your glass example you are (well, I was) assuming no fluorescence, perfectly elastic scattering  or complete absorption, had to neglect the thermal spectra, assumed non-radioactive materials etc.. These are all more or less OK assumptions for a piece of optical glass at room temperature when we are looking at it with a PMT, except for the radioactivity piece. Ordinary optical glass usually has a fairly high potassium content and a PMT will pick that up. :-)

Comment: So as the reflection changes from 0 to 16% how does it effect the transmitted? Are the two  proportional with a total that equals the source minus the abortion? Thanks

Comment: For a "passive" optical material transmitted, reflected and absorbed energy have to add up, yes. Can this be expressed with photon count? Yes... until you encounter "little problems" like natural radioactivity with your photon counter... or you are actually forced to be honest about thermodynamics because you are sensitive to deep IR light. You expect a trivial answer to a complex radiation/matter interaction problem. The most simple halfway complete model that you can look at are the Fresnel equations with complex dielectric constants. It only gets worse from there.

Comment: All photons are accounted for in theory.  I say in theory because if a photon vanishes from thin air, we'd have no way of knowing and assume it got absorbed.  There are limits to what we can measure, and certainly keeping track of say 1000 photons is only possible if you make certain assumptions, like that photons that seem to vanish are presumably absorbed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the world of linear optics we assume that $T+R+A=1$, Transmitted, Reflected, Absorbed.  For optical glass absorptance is very low, so set $A=0$.

This leads us to the result described in the comments: $T=1-R$.

I use this when doing quantum optics in the lab; in order to maximize transmission we use (a) fine optics that are designed for the wavelengths being used, (b) anti-reflection coatings, (c) the minimum number of passive optical elements required to get the job done.

In the end you will always lose some photons, but if the system works for large numbers of photons, it will also (most of the time) work for small numbers of photons.  This is because most passive optical devices can be modeled as unitary operators and there is (usually) no feedback into the laser cavity, so the experimental Hamiltonian isn't being perturbed.

Once you have your experiment setup and working properly you can test it with phase plates of various thickness, and report back if the quantum counting still agrees with the $T=1-R$ prediction.